# (de)serializing kotlin delegate properties with jackson

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, kotlin-delegate

How can I (de)serialize kotlin delegate properties with jackson.
I have a class like this

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    var a: Int = 42
        set(value) {
            val changed = field != value
            field = value
            if (changed) notifyListeners()
        }

    ... and a dozen other properties that all follow this pattern ...
}
```

I wanted to simplify that by using

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    var a: Int by NotifyUiOnChange(42)

    ...

    private inner class NotifyUiOnChange<T>(initialValue: T) : ObservableProperty<T>(initialValue) {
        override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: T, newValue: T) {
            notifyUiListeners()
        }
    }
}
```

but then Jackson will ignore that property.
How can I tell Jackson to serialize and deserialize that property anyway?
And how do I then apply @JsonIgnore annotations (or something comparable)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use outdated version on Jackson (or maybe a version for Java, not Kotlin?). I've checked this using `"com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.+"` (resolved to 2.10.1).

I've declared two classes:

```
class MyClass {
    var a: Int = 42
        set(value) {
            val changed = field != value
            field = value
            if (changed) notifyListener(field)
        }

    private fun notifyListener(field: Any?) {
        println("changed: $field")
    }
}

class MyDelegatedClass {
    var a: Int by NotifyUi(42)

    private inner class NotifyUi<T>(initialValue: T) : ObservableProperty<T>(initialValue) {
        override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: T, newValue: T) {
            notifyListener(newValue)
        }
    }

    private fun notifyListener(field: Any?) {
        println("changed: $field")
    }
}
```

My main function:

```
fun main() {
    val noDelegate = MyClass()
    val delegated = MyDelegatedClass()

    val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()

    // Deserialization 
    val noDelegateValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(noDelegate)
    val delegatedValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(delegated)

    println("No delegate:\t$noDelegateValue")
    println("With delegate\t$delegatedValue")

    // Serialization
    val noDelegateObject = mapper.readValue<MyClass>("{\"a\":42}".trimIndent())
    val delegateObject = mapper.readValue<MyDelegatedClass>("{\"a\":42}".trimIndent())

}
```

Output:

```
No delegate:    {"a":42}
With delegate   {"a":42}
changed: 42
```

We even can see output on delegate when we use delegate property :) (I believe it's a side-effect that should be consider as bug actually)

So, handling delegates is out of the box feature in jackson (I am not sure since when, but I used `lazy` delegate with `jackson` in older project I used to participate and there was no problems with delegates).

*How to ignore delegated property?*

So, you cannot apply `JsonIgnore` annotation to delegated field, because you will get `This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with delegate'`. But, you can define the scope that annotation should be applied. Example below:

```
class MyDelegateClass {
    @get:JsonIgnore // or set:
    val a: Int by NotifyUi(42)
}
```

Unfortunately, seems that it's kind of broken, because you can use `get:` or `set:` and it's not apply to getter or setter only, but for both.

Comment: Seems you're right. I don't know what I did wrong, but now it works as expected.

Comment: Still this leaves the question of how to ignore these properties again as I can't apply @JsonIgnore

Comment: I've added an explanation how to ignore property at all. I don't see a possibility to ignore only a getter or setter, maybe with other annotations.

Comment: Thanks. As I don't need ignoring only the getter or the setter, the trick with changing the annotation targed is enough for me